# Hide elements with jquery using selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hide

6 questions in 1. Say i have this:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <h3>blah</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Input 1:</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="some-input-a" name="some-input-a" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Input 2:</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="other-input" name="other-input" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h3>blah</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Input 3:</th>
                <td>
                    <select name="my-select" id="my-select">
                        <option value="1">My 1</option>
                        <option value="c">Your f</option>
                        <option value="m">This g</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Input 4:</th>
                <td><input type="password" id="pass-input" name="next-input" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Input 5:</th>
                <td><input type="password" id="pass-confirm" name="pass-confirm" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h3>blah</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Input 6:</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="next-one" name="next-one" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Input 7:</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="more-inputs" name="more-inputs" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Input 8:</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="form-input" name="form-input" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Input 9:</th>
                <td><textarea name="description" id="description" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Input 10:</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="input-10" name="input-10" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Is there an easy way to hide:

1. The third table completely
2. The row where the Textarea is
3. The row with the element who's ID is "description"
4. The 2nd row of the 3rd table
5. The 3rd `<h3>`
6. The fifth input label

Using selectors

Comment: Yes you can read the jQuery docs and surely you will find a solution http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: How about take a minute to read about jquery selectors ?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this, i was trying some ways to do this by myself, but i couldn't make them work. I used the selectors the way I understood them, but my knowledge is limited. Anyway, sorry for asking, I'll try not to do this anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.

```
$('form table:eq(2)').hide();
```

2.

```
$('form table tr').has('textarea').hide();
```

3.

```
$('#description').hide();
```

4.

```
$('form table:eq(2) tr:eq(1)').hide();
```

5.

```
$('form h3:eq(2)').hide();
```

6.

```
$('form input:eq(4)').parent().prev('td').hide();
```

Read about ***[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)***.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i did try: $( "form > table:eq( 2 )" ).hide(); but it didn't work for me. That's the main reason why i started asking. Is there any reason for this not to work?

Comment: That should work. Looks like the selector is right. Check the browser if you see any errors.. Its working in the fiddle

Comment: Thanks for your help. My original attempt was: $( "form#profile > table:eq( 3 )" ).hide(); , for some reason the > sign seems to be a problem, i just copied the code from somewhere else and now i see that makes it different.

Answer (score 1):

You use .hide() to hide the elements.. Also you have lot of repetitive questions. Try this

```
 1.) $('table:eq(2)').hide();

    2.) $('table tr').has('textarea').hide();

    3.) $('#description').parent().parent().hide();

    4.) $('table:eq(2) tr:eq(1)').hide();    

    5.) $('h3:eq(2)').hide();

    6.) $('table input:ep(4)').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would give you the answer check, because all your suggestions worked for me, but thecodeparadox answered first.